# Returning a count in a Case Satement Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to return a count of claims in `CASE` statement: Here is my select statement but only am getting back 1 and 0 as my results instead of the count.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT

            GROUP.Group_ID,
            GROUP.GROUP_NAME,

             SUM(DISTINCT CASE 
                WHEN TRUNC(CLAIM.PROCESS_DATE)-TRUNC(CLAIM.RECEIVED_DATE) < 11 THEN  '1'
                ELSE '0' 
                END) AS "0-10_DAYS",
                
             SUM(DISTINCT CASE 
                WHEN TRUNC(CLAIM.PROCESS_DATE)-TRUNC(CLAIM.RECEIVED_DATE) < 31 THEN '1'
                ELSE '0' 
                END) AS "0-30_DAYS"
```

I am looking to return number of claims that fall into these buckets after calculating process days.  I am new to SQL so any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Because you are using `SUM(DISTINCT )`. Don't use `DISTINCT` in the `SUM` or `SELECT` for this; use `GROUP BY GROUP.Group_ID, GROUP.GROUP_NAME` clause at the end instead.

Comment: `'1'` is a string literal, instead use `1` for the integer value.

Comment: BTW, those are `case` _expressions_, not statements.

Comment: You rarely never need to do SELECT DISTINCT when you do GROUP BY, because the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Thank you this has all been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the group by columns . GROUP.Group_ID, GROUP.GROUP_NAME,i.e in the group by clause.